# Is this a well constructed roof?

Tags: roof, construction, carpentry

Just took a closer look at the ridge of my roof and noticed that the angle between the ridge and virtually all the rafters is quite sloppy. Is that a problem is that the way these joints are supposed to look?[image]

[image]

Comment: All I can see on my phone is spray foam. The joint looks ok but on my phone is similar to looking at it from 20' away.

Comment: Does your roof structure have any horizontal members tying the sides together? Do the side walls lean ever so slightly outward ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These gaps are a normal occurrence when the framing dries out after cutting and setting in place.

As long as the rafter is tight at the top, you should have no concerns.